# Cannot add reference to a project using PrismXamarin

Tags: xamarin, prism

I have created a solution using Prism Template pack on visual studio 2017 enterprise edition.

1. I then add a cross platform.ClassLibrary "ClassLibrary1"
2. I then try to reference ClassLibrary1 (Portable) to my "MyProject (Portable) "
   and I get this error
   [image]

Any ideas why i get this error.Tried to change target and I get
[image]

Comment: Aren't the errors quite self explanatory? If you want to change target to NuGet 3.0 support, you need to remove all NuGet packages from the project. Change the target, then re-add the packages back. Referencing one PCL profile into another won't always work because of conflicting PCL profiles.

Comment: @Cheesebaron thanks for your reply.I thought that too .But it does not makes sense to me. why do I get the error in the first place I have just created the project and then tried to another one.why do I have todo all this work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin changed the profile of their class library to Profile111 when they dropped support for Win8.1.  So if you are using their class library then you need to update your PCL project to Profile111.  The easiest way to do this is to edit the csproj file and change this the TargetFrameworkProfile:

`<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>`

Comment: that worked thank you very much.I am a fan of prism and really appreciate your effort in your free time.I am new to xamarin world but some more meaty samples using modules in xamarin would be great